# Is com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE still in use?

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I've seen that c2dm itself is deprecated. But the new method, Google Cloud Messaging, seems to send intents with **com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE** as the action.

My code is using this to get the registration key:

```
gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
```

Things are arriving correctly, but I'm wondering if I've left something in a half-deprecated state.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE` is still in use. It is used when receiving a broadcast from GCM server that contains a GCM message. Even though C2DM is long deprecated, GCM still uses some names that contain `c2dm`.

As you can see in this manifest sample (taken from the [GCM guide](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html)), there are multiple places that still use names containing `c2dm` or `C2D` :

```
<manifest package="com.example.gcm" ...>
...
<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application ...>
    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
</application>
```

Comment: Ok cool, I've got those as well. It's confusing when you Google it and there's a big red paragraph telling you it's deprecated.

Comment: what should be the category? "com.example.gcm" or should I put there my app's package name?

Answer (score 5):

the `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE` is also used by the firebase cloud messaging

Comment: Is this still relevant? I’m using ```com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.6```

Answer (score 3):

As for the Receiver declaration

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Google suggested to replace BroadcastReceiver with the com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver, just like below.

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```